# how to get data from map._data typescript

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I have a simple map - `map<string, string>` I'm trying to get the key and values but only the ones who I added to the map.
the function gets the map as an observable map and my data is under _data key.
In the function below, I've tried to get only my data but it returns a lot of properties that I didn't create, How it's possible to get the data properly? also, why the map comes as observable?

```
function checkMap(valuesMap: Map<string, string>){     
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(valuesMap.values()).forEach(key => {
        let value = valuesMap[key];
        console.log(key, value);
        //use key and value here
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by using the `.keys()` method on the map:

```js
function checkMap(valuesMap: Map<string, string>){     
    [...valuesMap.keys()].forEach(key => {
        let value = valuesMap[key];
        console.log(key, value);
        //use key and value here
     });
}
```

the spread(`...`) [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) has to be used to convert the iterator from the `.keys()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) to a plain array.